# Is there a word for saying that $\Pr(A \mid B) = \Pr(B \mid A) = 1$?

Tags: probability, terminology

If I have two events $A$ and $B$, I can express the fact that $\Pr(A \cap B) = \Pr(A) \cdot \Pr(B)$ by saying that $A$ and $B$ are *independent*.

What word can I use to say that $\Pr(A \mid B) = \Pr(B \mid A) = 1$?

Comment: That seems to imply that $P(A)=P(B)=P(A\cap B)$. I don't know a word for that.

Comment: Could you give an example for that case? I think it  is a very special case!

Comment: Also A and B are identical up to sets of probability zero. I.e. $A=C\cup N_1$ and $B=C\cup N_2$ where the $N_i$ have probability zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition $$\Pr(A \mid B) = \Pr(B \mid A) = 1$$ is equivalent to $$\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}=\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(A)}=1.$$ The first equality gives $\Pr(A)=\Pr(B)$. The second gives $$-\Pr(A\cup B)+2\Pr(A)=\Pr(A\cap B) = \Pr(A).$$ Hence $$\Pr(A)=\Pr(B)=\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A\cup B).$$
So we can say that $A$ and $B$ are equally probable but there are more than that since there is also the equality with union and intersection. There is no special word for that in my knowledge.

Comment: This means they are identical up to a null set. Maybe a nice shorthand word be "null-equivalent" if such term doesn't already mean something else. But there are many complicated ways to be measure zero. I'd we are working with uniform(0,1) numbers then A and B could be (0.25,0.75) but A includes all rationals and B includes all rationals shifted by a specific irrational less that 0.25.

Answer (score 1):

$$P(A|B) = P(B|A) = 1$$

$$\iff$$

$$P(A) = P(B) = 1$$

Both A and B are **almost sure** to occur.

P.S. Almost sure events are independent of any other event, including themselves.